# Nested attributes with polymorphic association in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've created an `Address` model with a polymorphic association, I am trying to save to it though nested attributes of a client model but I am getting `Address addressable must exist` in the `@client.errors`.

Models:

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :address, as: :addressable, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Address < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Controller:

```
class ClientsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @client = Client.new
    @client.create_address
  end

  def create
    @client = Client.new(client_params)

    if @client.save
      ...
    else
      ...
    end
  end

  private
  def client_params
    params.require(:client).permit(:first_name ,:last_name, :company, address_attributes: [:line1, :line2, :line3, :city, :state_province, :postal_code, :country])
  end    
end
```

Answer (score 6):

You should add the [`inverse_of`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Setting+Inverses) key on your `belongs_to` relation, e.g. on your `Address` class:

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true, inverse_of: :addressable
end
```

This will save the nested address correctly as Rails will now correctly know what to assign in the `addressable`.

Don't use the `optional` key unless the `addressable` is truly optional.

Answer (score 4):

```
 belongs_to :xx, polymorphic: true, optional: true
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Here is some context: see [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/23960) and [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/29781).
Sounds like a bug to me: the `belongs_to` validator runs *before* the `polymorphic: true` which encounters an empty association.

Comment: Problem is that Rails doesn't know what to assign to the `addressable` while creating the nested `Address`, but you can tell Rails that by using the `inverse_of` option in your `belongs_to` relation, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37093554/nested-attributes-with-polymorphic-association-in-rails-5/53616444#53616444

Answer (score 2):

Also

```
optional: true
```

tricking the problem, you may keep relationships mandatory by breaking creation in controller in two steps.

```
def client_params
  params.require(:client).permit(:first_name ,:last_name, :company)
end

def address_params 
 params.require(:client).require( :address_attributes).permit(:line1, :line2, :line3, :city, :state_province, :postal_code, :country )
end

def create
  @client = Client.new(client_params)

  if @client.save
   @client.create_address( address_params )
  ...
```

this may look uglier but it keeps relations safer.

Comment: When separated into two actions what happens when @client saves successfully and the address creation fails ? Surely we would want both to fail at the same time and return an error to the form rather than save just one?

Comment: Good notice. I think this is the time when your models relations will dictate the right choice to make. If client can't exist without address and vice verse than you may need to add more complex logic around :(.

Comment: An explicit transaction with manual rollbacks would solve the issue of atomicity in this solution.

Comment: Don't use the `optional` key unless it's truly optional, instead use the `inverse_of` key as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37093554/nested-attributes-with-polymorphic-association-in-rails-5/53616444#53616444